# Login_required error but only for some users

Tags: identityserver4

We are using Identity Server 4 in an aspnetcore server app with oidc-client.js lib in an angular client.  There is a 15 minute token refresh. This is mostly working very well.

Hopwever, for a subset of users when the refresh activity takes place there is a "login_required" response. I am assuming this is because the ID4 server thinks the session cookie has expired? However, the user had just logged in 15 minutes prior and the cookie should have a lifetime of 10 hours (ID4 default setting).

Does anyone have an idea of what may be causing this? Alternatively is there any logging setting I can use to get more debug info?

Thank you!

We tried various browsers and logins but the behaviour is consistent for these users.

Answer (score 0):

refresh token flow so you may be using code flow with angular
so you have one client also for angular for login.
I faced this same issue because the same user logged in with multiple pc so when anyone logged out of his session all same users also logged out in the code flow.

Comment: Hi Rajat.  I really appreciate your response thank you. Each user is impacted independantly of the others.

I do have more detail now: IDS4 is logging "Showing login: User is not authenticated".  (But this is just 15 mins after they logged in, on the first refresh attempt.  So they should still be authenticated.)

Comment: The IDS4 source code shows this function for the IsAuthenticated() extension on Principal.  Not very helpful as I dont know which of these is the issue.  Perhaps the principle or Identity are null for instance.

        public static bool IsAuthenticated(this IPrincipal principal)
        {
            return principal != null && principal.Identity != null && principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }

Comment: thank you 
please use this line to check more info
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

Comment: Ys I will do that and let you know.

In the meantime there is also more information:

If I start an Incognito window, go to the IDS4 server and login successfuly and then go the Angular app, when the token refresh is attempted the request Principle is not authenticated. I see in the logs:
"SubjectId":"anonymous"

(annd thank you again for your time!)

Comment: in Incognito mode cookies is not hold in browser then token is requested again and again in IDS4 on code flow with refresh token mode
and for more info implicit flow is not support properly with angular in refresh token